# How do synthetic homotopy groups relate to the usual homotopy groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homotopy-type-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

In Homotopy Type Theory (HoTT in what follows) one may compute homotopy groups of objects that bear names that are the same as some usual spaces: for instance one may consider $S^1$ which is defined by $*:S^1, b : *=_{S^1}*$ and with the usual induction principle, and compute its homotopy groups.

It has been proved for instance that with this definition $\pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$ and the higher homotopy groups vanish, which coincides with the usual homotopy groups of the usual $S^1$.

Now it seems that all the homotopy groups that have been computed in HoTT so far (say of spheres) coincide with the usual ones (in the sense that they have the same description : we can't literally compare them because they don't live in the same theory). My question is : how much of it is a coincidence ? I expect that it's *not* a coincidence, and so my real question is actually : can we explain it ? If so, in what terms ?

I'm not asking for a proof, but my problem is, the result seems even hard to state (as I said : the groups are not living in the same theory, and to begin how do we even relate HoTT's $S^1$ with the usual $S^1$ ? ).

So I would want an answer that explains how to *state* the result (not necessarily the details, but at least the main ideas), and *how* to prove it (again, the main ideas of proof - I expect something like "oh so we have this model of HoTT that we can define in set theory, and when you interpret HoTT in this model, $S^1$ looks like the circle and its homotopy groups look like the usual homotopy groups")

Comment: It would be nice if your question was just a little more self contained. After finally reading your tags I figured out that HoTT probably means "homotopy type theory", but I have no clue what the string of symbols $*:S^1, b : *=_{S^1}*$ means.

Comment: @LeeMosher I added the meaning of HoTT, but it's complicated to add what $*:S^1$ means : it's just a type-theoretic judgment, that $*$ is of type $S^1$; and similarly $b$ is of type $*=_{S^1}*$ (the identity type). If you know what that means, then you'll know what the symbols mean, and if you don't, I encourage you to go read about type theory, it's very interesting :) You can understand it as something saying "$*$ is an element of $S^1$ and $b$ is a path from $*$ to itself; the induction principle guarantees that it is a "generic" loop"

Comment: This question seems interesting but given that it's rather advanced and about the forefront of current research it might be more suited to mathoverflow.

Comment: @William : I didn't post there because I wasn't sure it was actually at the forefront of current research. Now that I've posted here, I think it's best to wait a bit - if there are no answers or if more people agree with you, I will cross post it to MO

Comment: I don't know enough (about the homotopy side) to write a proper answer to this. However, part of the point is that types in homotopy type theory 'are' ∞-groupoids, and there are ways of defining them by giving certain algebraic presentations. So (I think), what people do is try to define the fundamental ∞-groupoid of a space with an appropriate presentation. Then the groups are just slices of this groupoid. So it is no coincidence, because they know what the groupoid is supposed to be, attempt to define it synthetically, and then call it by the same name. Does that help at all?

Comment: @DanDoel : well I kind of knew that it was no coincidence, and that the groupoids we defined try to model the spaces (for instance I understand what the HoTT definition of $S^1$ is trying to do), but my question is more : how do we know that it *actually* models it, and in what sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All homotopy groups that can be computed in HoTT coincide with the corresponding classical homotopy groups.  This is because HoTT has an interpretation in the Quillen model category of simplicial sets (constructed in a metatheory of ZFC plus some inaccessible cardinals, although probably a much weaker theory suffices), constructed by [Voevodsky](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2851), which is also Quillen equivalent to classical homotopy theory.  Thus, any calculation in HoTT can be interpreted into simplicial sets and then transferred across that equivalence to classical homotopy theory.

A much more interesting (and open!) question is whether every computation of a classical homotopy group is also provable in HoTT.  This is interesting and nontrivial because the really interesting thing about HoTT (from my point of view) is that it also has lots of *other* models, namely in all [higher toposes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.07004).  Thus, this question is tantamount to asking whether the homotopy groups of spheres (say) are the same in all higher toposes.

(Technical fine print: we know by an extrinsic argument that the homotopy groups of spheres and other finite complexes are the same in all "Grothendieck" higher toposes, but there are also [other models](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06649), and reasoning about any particular class of models can't answer the question of what can be proven *internally* in HoTT.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Just to make sure, about the first paragraph : this interpretation of HoTT in ssets, does it interpret $S^1$ for instance as one of the known simplicial models of the circle ? And so on for higher spheres ? And regarding your last paragraph, is there some sort of completeness theorem for HoTT with respect to some class of models ? (Your answer suggests that it's not true, or at least not known for $\infty$-topoi)

Comment: Yes to the first question; the interpretation of $S^1$ and other higher inductive types is described in https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07088, in terms of homotopy pushouts in a model category which are also a known way to construct spheres.

Comment: @Max For the second question, there is the usual sort of tautological completeness theorem in that a "Lindenbaum-Tarski" model can be constructed directly out of the syntax, so that anything true in "all models" must be true in that model and hence provable.  However, we don't yet have a naturally defined class of higher categories in which HoTT can be interpreted that includes the syntactic model, due to coherence issues; the syntactic model is naturally a strict sort of gadget rather than a higher-categorical one.

Comment: Thank you ! And ok for completeness, I was indeed expecting some sort of Lindenbaum-Tarski process to be applicable here, but  was wondering about a "natural" class as you put it. Thank you for all your answers !